# How to make twitter links open in a new window

Tags: html

On my site the twitter links open in the parent window. I can't find any reference to the links in the HTML any ideas how to make them open in a new window?

[www.wefewlondon.com](http://www.wefewlondon.com)

Thanks

Comment: How are the links being added to your page?

Comment: I'm guessing via the javascript file. Sorry bit new to this :)

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your questions and don't make people go to another site and dig around.

Comment: use jquery to add target="_blank" to all links int that slider control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tweet markup is generated by the [jQuery.tweet](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/) plugin. They explain how to achieve the desired outcome in example #6 on their homepage.

Effectively, all you need to do is add this line at line 33 of your main.js:

```
$(this).find("a").attr("target","_blank");
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works like a dream!

Answer (score 1):

I looked at your javascript/lib/jquery.tweet.js file.. look at the

```
 return "<a href=\""+escapeHTML(url)+"\">"+escapeHTML(text)+"</a>";
```

part... add "target="_blank" and that should do it

```
return "<a href=\""+escapeHTML(url)+"\ target=_blank>"+escapeHTML(text)+"</a>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Where the link is written, for example here:

```
<a href=\"http://"+s.twitter_url+"/$2\">$2</a>
```

You can append the target attribute:

```
<a href=\"http://"+s.twitter_url+"/$2\" target=\"_blank\">$2</a>
```